# Best way to provide skin options in my application?

Tags: android, textures, skin

I want to provide the user of my application an option to choose a skin from a number of skins in application where basically I need to assign a different set of textures to objects such as `TextViews`, `LinearLayouts` and `ImageViews`. Some are assigned using code and some using the xml layout resource files.

From my point of view I could create a section in my application's settings/shared preferences screen (using one option selectable checkboxes/radiobuttons ),move all assigned texture to code based assignments and assigned the needed set of textures in code for all my objects.

But it sound like a huge amount of work that I would really like to avoid and I was wondering if there is another way to add this functionality, maybe some more "android" and not "java" way to add this functionality to my application?

Please share if you have provided this option in your application and how you did it.
More reading content about this topic is very welcome as well.